# how to create SQL Lite Schema

Tags: sqlite, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm retrospectively unit testing a zend application and want to use an SQL Lite database for convenience. In production we use MySQL updated with DB migrations. Simple question: How do I create an SQL Lite schema? Is it possible to automatically recreate the schema inside phpunit?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using doctrine?

If so, you can generate the schema with doctrine's `orm:schema-tool:create` feature.

You can use this command to either dump the SQL, or generate your tables directly through the connection.